# iOS UITextView's textContainer Text Cut Off When Resizing

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nstextcontainer

I have a `UITextView` that I am resizing using a `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`:

```
@IBAction func handlePinch(recognizer : UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    if let view = recognizer.view {
      view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(view.transform,
        recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale)

        recognizer.scale = 1
    }
        self.textView.textContainer.size = self.textView.bounds.size
  }
```

All my text is displayed until I resize the `UITextView` using the above func. Once I resize smaller, the `textContainer` is smaller in both height and width. I have tried to change `bounds.size` to `frame.size`. I have `autoresizesubview = true` already. Can't figure this one out...I have tried almost everything.

Comment: Is the gesture recognizer added to the UITextView or another view? Also, the last line isn't needed since the bounds will not change.

Comment: Yes, the gesture recognizer is added to the UITextView. Also, I tried it without the last line and you are correct, it is not needed. Thanks! textContainer still resizing though.

Comment: I figured out half of my problem. I set myTextView.clipstobounds = false in my viewDidLoad. This fixed my height of my textContainer from being cut off. However, it still cuts off my width.

Comment: @B.Wolf what was the solution for this?